# How to create ThemeShadow programmatically? (C# UWP 1903)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I tried to create `ThemeShadow` programmatically but cannot solve the `Resources` part in `XAML`. I call the `void` like this: `CreateTheme(Test,SharedShadow);`. I like to rid of the part `SharedShadow` on call `void` parameters than I can make it works without code in `XAML`. How to do that?

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <!--HOW TO MAKE THIS PART (RESOURCES) PROGRAMMATICALLY?-->
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ThemeShadow x:Name="SharedShadow" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Rectangle x:Name="Test" Width="200" Height="70" Fill="DarkGray" Shadow="{StaticResource SharedShadow}"></Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Void - C#

```
public static void CreateTheme(FrameworkElement TargetFrameworkElement, ThemeShadow SharedShadow)
{
    //In this case we know the Parent will be Grid...
    Grid TargetGrid = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(TargetFrameworkElement) as Grid;
    //Create the Grid for Shadow        
    Grid ShadowGrid = new Grid() {Margin=new Thickness(-16) };
    //Insert it as first element in its Parent
    TargetGrid.Children.Insert(0, ShadowGrid);
    //Recievers
    SharedShadow.Receivers.Add(ShadowGrid);
    //Translation
    TargetFrameworkElement.Translation += new Vector3(0, 0, 16);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved finally. The following code works very well. Just call `void` like this: `CreateTheme(Test, 16);` `Test` is name of `Rectangle` and `16` is `Depth` of shadow.

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle x:Name="Test" Width="200" Height="70" Fill="DarkGray"></Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
    public static void CreateTheme(FrameworkElement TargetFrameworkElement, int ZDepth)
    {
        //MAKE SURE THAT PARENT IS TYPE OF GRID
        if (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(TargetFrameworkElement) is Grid)
        {
            //GET PARENT GRID
            Grid ParentGrid = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(TargetFrameworkElement) as Grid;
            //CREATE BORDER FOR SHADOW (RECIEVER). MAKE SURE THERE ARE SPACE TO SHOW SHADOW SO SET MARGIN NEGATIVE.
            Border ShadowReciever = new Border() { Margin = new Thickness(-ZDepth) };
            //ADD RECIEVER TO PARENT GRID
            ParentGrid.Children.Insert(0, ShadowReciever);
            //CREATE NEW THEME SHADOW
            ThemeShadow SharedShadow = new ThemeShadow();
            //CONNECT SHADOW TO FRAMEWORK ELEMENT
            TargetFrameworkElement.Shadow = SharedShadow;
            //CONNECT RECIEVER TO THEME SHADOW
            SharedShadow.Receivers.Add(ShadowReciever);
            //SET SHADOW DEPTH
            TargetFrameworkElement.Translation += new Vector3(0, 0, ZDepth);
        }
        else
        {
            //ERROR. PARENT MUST BE TYPE OF GRID
        }
    }
```